# Return HashMap using SOAP in java

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

i have service with two operation as fellow

```
@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")

public class NewWebService {

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     * @param txt
     * @return 
     */
     @WebMethod(operationName = "GetAvailableOptions")
    public List<String> GetAvailableOptions(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt ) {

        newpackage.StringArray arr = new newpackage.StringArray();
        List<String> listopt = arr.getList();

        endicia.MainStarter main = new endicia.MainStarter();
        main.renderMsg(txt);
        listopt = main.getOpt();
        listopt = main.getOpt();


        return listopt;
    }

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     * @param type
     * @param nMap
     * @return 
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetLabel")
    public HashMap<String,String> GetLabel(@WebParam(name = "name") String type,@WebParam(name = "values")HashMap<String,String> nMap) {
        String categoryName = type;
        HashMapWrapper getLabel = new HashMapWrapper();
        HashMap<String,String> response = getLabel.getMap();

        endicia.MainStarter main = new endicia.MainStarter();
        main.renderMsg(categoryName, nMap);

        response = main.getHashMap();

        return response ;
    }
}
```

when i following url in browser it give simple response of invalid wsdl request.

```
http://localhost:8080/WebApplication/NewWebService?WSDL
```

but when i comment 2nd operation that is returning hashmap and hit URL gain, its work fine.

Now i think issue is on returning hashmaps.

Any one know how to resolve this issue.

below is my wrapper class

```
public class HashMapWrapper {

     private HashMap<String, String> nMap;

    public HashMapWrapper() {

        this.nMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    }

    public HashMap<String,String> getMap(){

        return this.nMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using glassfish-4.0 with netbeans 8.0.

Comment: It's more likely to be the parameter of a map called values.

Comment: @DanTemple can you please elborate this point. i am stuck on it for whole day

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing that your issue likely relates to the fact that you are expecting the second service to be able to accept a HashMap as one of it's parameters. Usually when you have complex data types like that, there is some mapping from the SOAP (XML) request to an specific object for the Request, perhaps via JAXB or something similar. I'm not sure how your SOAP request is going to be able to represent just a raw HashMap and how your service is going to be able to convert between the two.